# About Xml file in visual c++

Tags: visual-c++

I am new to xml and visual c++.Now i have to save some data from visual c++ using c++ windows form application into xml file and read them back .Please Help.....

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Windows Forms, you can use System::Xml to serialize your data. This is wrapped up nicely in the LocalFileSettingsProvider class which persists a class derived by ApplicationSettingsBase. [In C# or VB you can just add a settings file, but the settings designer is not available in Visual C++, you need to wire up the classes manually.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8eyb2ct1.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a library that should do the heavy lifting for you: http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/index.html

If that doesn't work for you, there are MANY C++ XML libraries on the net. Google shall provide!